# String escaping with twig?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

QUESTION:

How do you append the following twig variable at the end of the first parameter of the anchor function?

```
{{ anchor('welcome/play/', 'Play', {'class': 'btn btn-primary'})|raw }}
```

I have tried variations of: 'welcome/play/{{t.CompetitionID}}' etc which doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `~` to concatenate strings http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#expressions :

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello
>   " ~ name ~ "!" }} would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!.

Thus:

```
{{ anchor('welcome/play/' ~ t.competitionID, 'Play', {'class': 'btn btn-primary'})|raw }}
```